# Need Delphi 6 example for updating a progress bar during TIdSmtp send operation, especially for large attachments

Tags: delphi, smtp, progress-bar, indy

I am using the Indy TIdSmtp component to send E-mails.  The E-mails I am sending will have a large attachment, usually in the range of 5 to 40 MB.  I want to update a progress bar that will show the overall progress of the send as a percentage of the total number of bytes that need to be sent.  I don't care if it's really precise, just good enough to give someone watching the progress bar an indication for how far along the overall E-mail sending process is.

Can someone point me to a code sample that shows me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TIdSMTP` encodes the email on-the-fly as it is being sent to the server.  The total number of bytes being sent is not known ahead of time.  The only way you would be able to determine a value even reasonably close is to encode the email to a temporary `TStream` via the `TIdMessage.SaveToStream()` method and then grab the value of the `TStream.Size` property.  Since you are encoding large attachments, that will take some time and lots of memory overhead.  Since `TIdSMTP` will just re-encode the email again during transmission, there is no guarantee that the number of bytes actually transmitted will match the temp `TStream.Size` due to the dynamic nature of various email headers, such as timestamps and MIME boundaries.

To determine how many bytes are actually being sent, use the `TIdSMTP.OnWork...` events, where the `AWorkMode` parameter will be set to `wmWrite`.  Since `TIdSMTP.Send()` does not know ahead of time how many bytes it will be sending, the `AWorkCountMax` parameter of the `TIdSMTP.OnWorkBegin` event will be `0`, but at least you will know when the actual email data begin encoding/sending (after `TIdSMTP` has exchanged several commands with the server).  The `AWorkCount` parameter of the `TIdSMTP.OnWork` event will be the total number of bytes actually sent.  When the `TIdSMTP.OnWorkEnd` event is fired, the email has finished being sent.

Based on the temp `TStream.Size` property and the `AWorkCount` parameter of the `TIdSMTP.OnWork` event, you will be able to display an approximation of a percentage for a progress bar.  It will not be guaranteed to be 100% accurate, but it will be close.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I needed.  Anything is better than a PC that appears to be hung for an inordinate period of time.  At least my users will see the progress bar doing something so they know my app hasn't locked up.  Even if I do something grossly inaccurate like multiply the total size of the attachments by 2 and divide it by AWorkCount to get a percentage, at least there will be some visual feedback.

Comment: To minimize the overhead of encoding a temporary stream, you can use Indy's public `TIdDiscardStream` or `TIdEventStream` class, or copy the implementation of Indy's private `TIdCalculateSizeStream` class from the `IdMulipartFormData.pas` unit. That way, no data is being stored in memory, but you can still tally up how many bytes are written to the stream.