# Adding Tprogressbar to track transfer time on events to Tidsmtp using IdSSLOHandler, IdMessage and Idatachmentfile

Tags: delphi, smtp, progress-bar, delphi-xe2, indy10

I looked at http://www.delphigroups.info/2/93/183240.html where Lee J Coo gives an example of making a email send progress tracking form using TidSmtp and idmessage.

When i try to emulate the code it happens that before anything it sends me a message of `connection closed gracefully` ive seen another posts where `Remy Lebeau` suggest something similar [Need Delphi 6 example for updating a progress bar during TIdSmtp send operation, especially for large attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611038/need-delphi-6-example-for-updating-a-progress-bar-during-tidsmtp-send-operation).

I dont know if something is wrong with the `TIdAttachmentFile.Create(Idmessage1.MessageParts,)`

Im putting my effort on this but looking at suggestions like use savetofile instead of savetostream, this thing about `connection closed gracefully` seems pretty common and can't give too much insights of the problem but maybe someone can tell from experience.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611038/need-delphi-6-example-for-updating-a-progress-bar-during-tidsmtp-send-operation), Indy 10 has a `TIdEventStream` class in the `IdGlobal` unit that you can use to keep track of how many bytes `TIdMessage.SaveToStream()` encodes without having to waste any memory or filesystem space at all.  There is also a private `TIdCalculateSizeStream` class in the `IdMultipartFormDataStream` unit that does the same thing.  You can copy that class into your project's code.

If you are having problems using either class, you need to provide specific details.

With that said, you should "encode" the email to get its estimated size before you connect to the SMTP server, not after you connect.  If the encoding takes awhile, the SMTP server might time out and close the connection on its end before you have a chance to call `Send()` to transmit the email (which will re-encode it again and take just as long, if not longer, than the first temporary encode).